# Calculate total running time of pods using two date/timestamp columns

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query

I am currently storing all the pods in PostgreSQL db. I track each pods creation and deletion through **created_time** and **deleted_time** column. When pod is not deleted, its **deleted_time** columns remains null.

SqlFiddle can be found here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd5cb/8)

The schema is given below for quick reference:

```
create table pods (
  name text primary key,
  created_time timestamp without time zone,
  deleted_time timestamp without time zone default null
);

insert into pods (name, created_time)
values
('pod-1', '02-01-2020 01:00:00'),
('pod-2', '02-01-2020 02:00:00');

update pods set deleted_time = '02-01-2020 03:00:00' where name = 'pod-1';
```

The challenges while calculating the running time are as follows:

1. Handling NULL values in **deleted_time** column (pod is still running)
2. Clipping **created_time** and **deleted_time** to a user-specific range (start and end time).

So I came up with following query which calculates the usage hours, but it's a bit slow when you are dealing with million of pods in a selected date range.

```
-- end_time = '2020-02-01 04:00:00'
-- start_time = '2020-02-01 02:00:00'

with model as (
  select
    name,
    case when created_time < '2020-02-01 02:00:00' then '2020-02-01 02:00:00' else created_time end as created_time,
    coalesce(
      case when deleted_time >= created_time and deleted_time <= '2020-02-01 04:00:00' then deleted_time else null end,
      '2020-02-01 04:00:00'
    ) as deleted_time,
    extract(
      epoch from(
          coalesce(
          case when deleted_time >= created_time and deleted_time <= '2020-02-01 04:00:00' then deleted_time else null end, '2020-02-01 04:00:00'
          ) - case when created_time < '2020-02-01 02:00:00' then '2020-02-01 02:00:00' else created_time end)) / 3600::float as usage_hours
  from pods
  where created_time <= '2020-02-01 04:00:00' and
        (deleted_time is null or deleted_time >= '2020-02-01 02:00:00')
)
select sum(usage_hours) from model; -- should return 3.
```

So here are my questions:

1. I would like to know if there is any more efficient way to calculate these statistics?
2. Is it even possible to calculate it with the given schema?

Comment: Please do no cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205226/calculate-total-running-time-of-pods-using-two-date-timestamp-columns Furthermore, check https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and add the relevant detail mentioned there (especially indexes, the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and the number of exepcted rows, plus what you see as acceptable performance).